# How to enable Windows Authentication for DNN

Tags: sql-server-2008, dotnetnuke

Sorry my question might be duplicate but i dint find any correct solution.So im posting this question again...

First i have deployed a DNN website with sql server authentication.Site was working fine.
Later we re installed the sql server 2008. So im trying to give windows authentication to connect the site.

In web config connectionstring:i have removed the username and password and gave Integrated security="true" .

In IIS :Site -> Authentication -> windows Authentication  ->enabled and all others disabled.

once i browse  the site is redirecting to DNN install Wizard

Need Help.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server did you configure the Windows account that the application pool (in IIS) is using to have DBOwner access to the database?

Also make sure to change BOTH connection strings in the database.

Depending on what version of IIS you are on, that account might differ. Older versions likely would use "Network Service" while newer versions might also use "Network Service" or an application pool specific account like "iis apppool\dnndev"

You'll also want to make sure that you aren't trying to assign a DOMAIN account to the database, unless of course that is what IIS is configured to use (as opposed to a local account)